# Using Youtube API to return parts of parts [Python]?

Tags: python, api, youtube

Working with the Youtube API v3 to try and pull data from a channel's playlists. I can see their playlists (or at least the default favorites, likes, and uploads) and want to pull more specific content from them. However, when I try to call Youtube.channels().list and then specify part as contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads, I get an unknown part error, which is confusing because Youtube API says it should work and return a string, which shouldn't have an error printing. What am I doing wrong here? Will include code below.

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "./CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads",
        id="UCtcUKdcAXfVCo5YlgBMkfjA"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `part=contentDetails` to comply with [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#part) YouTube Data API v3 documentation and `print(response["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"])` as you would notice that `response` is just a [Python dictionnary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and by priting `response` or looking at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#response) you can guess the path of keys to access the value you are looking for, that is `items/0/contentDetails/relatedPlaylists/uploads`.

Comment: thank you so much, that fixed the issue for me. If you don't mind explaining, what is the "[0]" used for here? I'm assuming it's because the "contentDetails" it's looking for is part of the first argument of the items list since it's all bracketed? Just want to make sure I understand it.